# incorrect recurse function using cURL

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Codeignite controller I have two functions: **index** and **get_data**. Index get `$_POST` value from **textarea** and init **get_data** for each adress **(new line in textarea=new adress)**.

**Index Function:**

```
public function index()
{
    if (isset($_POST['wartosc'])) {
      $adresy = explode("\n", $_POST['wartosc']);
      foreach ($adresy as $lista_adresow) {
            $data['wynik'] = $this->get_data($lista_adresow);
      }
    }
    var_dump($data['wynik']);
    $this->load->view('wynik', $data);
}
```

**Get_data** function use **cURL** to get info about adress(IP, redirect url, http code itp). Example how this function must work:

`$_POST['wartosc']='youtube.pl'=>index init get_data()=>cURL` return adress ip, http code, and redirect_url and here is my problem because if address have **redirect_url** i must recall function `get_data()` again (it must be recursive function) until `redirect_url==NULL` and return all redirect with ip and http code to index function and assign to `$data['wynik']` but I get only part of data.

**Get Data Function:**

```
function get_data($adres)
{
    $url = $adres;
    $c = curl_init();
    $opcje = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
    );
    curl_setopt_array($c, $opcje);
    curl_exec($c);
    $info = curl_getinfo($c);
    if (curl_errno($c)) {
        echo 'Błąd #' . curl_errno($c) . ': ' . curl_error($c) . "<br>";
    };
    $tablica = array() + $info;
    if ($tablica['redirect_url'] != NULL) {
     $this->get_data($tablica['redirect_url']);
    }

    return $tablica;
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: "I only get part of data". Which part? What is missing, what are you expecting?

Comment: I think recurse don't work, get_data return info only for first adress without recall function for redirect adresses

Comment: maybe you need to debug then and see what $tablica['redirect_url'] actually looks like and see whether it's passing your NULL test or not, or whether it contains a valid URL that your function can then use when recursing. Or simply add a counter so you can see how many times the method's been called, and echo that

Comment: Use var_dump(return $tablica) instead of return $tablica in get_data function get this: https://s4.postimg.io/eko8p8izx/image.png and that i need but when use return $tablica and var_dump($wynik) in index function: https://s4.postimg.io/thwpq8w8d/image.png I don't know why :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you run get_data, you return $tablica. But if that's run from a preceding call to get_data, it throws away the return value from the later call.

```
$this->get_data($tablica['redirect_url']);
```

doesn't store the return value from get_data.

So you'll only ever get back the first result, no matter how many times you call it recursively.

You need to either bubble up the return values through the recursion, or directly store them in some other variable.

e.g. you could have a property of your class called "results" (you can think of a better name!) which is an array, and then do this:

```
$this->results[] = $this->get_data($tablica['redirect_url']);
```

Likewise your initial call to get_data (outside the recursion) should store the output in results.

Then finally do something like this:

```
$data['wynik'] = $this->results;
```

Or maybe you need it all merged to a string or something, just do it however it needs to be.

Comment: Create results array in get_data and return at function end?

Comment: you'd have to create the array outside the function (e.g. in your constructor). Within the function you only append to it. If you create it within the function, you'll overwrite it every time you call the function (and have the same problem you've got now).

Comment: Oh and send it to get_data as second parametr

Comment: no you don't need to if it's a property within the same class. `$this->results` will give you access to it, just like my example.